# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline Indexing Issue

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

Good day,

I am trying to setup a Multibranch pipeline on our new Jenkins instance and I encountered this error in the *Scan Multibranch Pipeline Log*:

**No such file: E:\Continuous Integration\Jenkins\jobs\Enhanced-API\indexing\indexing.log**

According to jenkins.err.log, I encountered a

`WARNING: Caught exception evaluating: h.filterDescriptors(it,attrs.descriptors) in /view/EAPI/job/Enhanced-API/configure. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException: Descriptor list is null for context 'class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject' in thread 'Handling GET /view/EAPI/job/Enhanced-API/configure from 10.117.100.110 : RequestHandlerThread[#35] AbstractFolder/configure.jelly FolderLibraries/DescriptorImpl/config.jelly LibraryConfiguration/config.jelly SCMRetriever/DescriptorImpl/config.jelly MultiSCM/DescriptorImpl/config.jelly'
java.lang.NullPointerException: Descriptor list is null for context 'class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject' in thread 'Handling GET /view/EAPI/job/Enhanced-API/configure from 10.117.100.110 : RequestHandlerThread[#35] AbstractFolder/configure.jelly FolderLibraries/DescriptorImpl/config.jelly LibraryConfiguration/config.jelly SCMRetriever/DescriptorImpl/config.jelly MultiSCM/DescriptorImpl/config.jelly'
    at hudson.model.DescriptorVisibilityFilter.apply(DescriptorVisibilityFilter.java:73)
    at hudson.Functions.filterDescriptors(Functions.java:1863)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor293.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:258)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:83)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:57)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReferenceExpression.value(ASTReferenceExpression.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.ExpressionImpl.evaluate(ExpressionImpl.java:80)
    at hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression.evaluate(ExpressionFactory2.java:74)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$3.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:134)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)`

The version of this Jenkins is **2.85** with the following versions of Git plugin:

Git client plugin - 2.5.0

Git plugin - 3.6.0

GIT server Plugin - 1.7

GitHub API Plugin - 1.89

GitHub Branch Source Plugin - 2.2.3

GitHub plugin - 1.28.0

Any idea on why did we encounter this issue? Thanks!

Comment: In addition to this, our Git project was not indexed and no Jenkins job was created..

Answer (score 0):

This might help: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39598

The plugin causing it is deprecated but apparently a workaround is this (I've not tested it):

```
touch $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/multiple-scms.jpi.disabled
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, nor did uninstalling it thru the plugin manager.